# Invalid object name dbo.Table1 error in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have the following tables: `StudentCourses` is a mapping table of `Student` and `Course`

- `Student` (Id, ..)
- `Course` (Id, ..)
- `StudentCourses` (StudentId, CourseId)

Model classes:

```
public class Student {
      ....
      ....
      public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } 

}

public class Course {
      ...
      ...
      public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } 
}

public class StudentCourse  {
      ...
      ...
      public virtual Student Student { get; set; } 
}
```

Mappings are set as below:

```
public class StudentConfiguration
      : EntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
      public StudentConfiguration()
      {
         HasKey(x => x.Id);

         //Many to many
         HasMany(s => s.Course)
            .WithMany(t => t.Students)
            .Map(x =>
            {
               x.ToTable("StudentCourses");
               x.MapLeftKey("StudentId");
               x.MapRightKey("CourseId");
            }
            );
        }
}

public class StudentCourseConfiguration
      : EntityTypeConfiguration<StudentCourse>
{
      public StudentCourseConfiguration()
      {
         HasKey(x => new {x.StudentId, x.CourseId});
      }
}
```

I am trying to get a collection of `Courses` with with the number of students enrolled for each course.

```
public ActionResult GetAllCourseInfo()
{
         var courses = _context.Course.ToList();
         var courseInfo = new List<CourseInfo>();

         foreach (var course in courses )
         {
            var studentCount = _context.StudentCourse.Count(x => x.Student.CourseName.Equals(course.CourseName));
            courseInfo.Add(new CourseInfo{ CourseName = course.CourseName, Count = studentCount });
         }

         return Json(courseInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I am getting an exception

> Invalid object name dbo.StudentCourses1

1. How do I resolve this?
2. Is my `EntityTypeConfiguration` correct?

Comment: Have you modified at all the code Entity Framework generates? Have you searched for "StudentCourses1" in all your solution?

Comment: No, haven't modified any autogenerated code. This is a "code first" solution for an existing DB. There is no StudentCourses1 in my solution at all.

Comment: Your fluent configuration is for `many-to-many` with **implicit** junction table, while you have an explicit `StudentCourse` entity. Either the model should be changed or `StudentCourse` entity should be removed. Do you have fields other  than `StudentId, CourseId` in it?

Comment: How do I change model to make junction table explicit?

Comment: You need to change the type of the navigation properties to `ICollection<StudentCourse>` and configure 2 `one-to-many` relationships.